Do $\sum_{i=1}^mi$ and $\sum_{n=1}^mn$ mean the same thing?
I'm trying to learn Sigma Notation, but whenever I look it up, I see different letters for the lower bound. eg $i=1$ or $n=1$ like
$$
\sum_{i=1}^mi\quad\text{ or }\quad\sum_{n=1}^mn
$$
Is it the same thing with different letters?

You choose the names for your variables.

Yeah the letter does not affect the meaning.

I tried to fix the formatting of the formulas. That said, have you tried to read Wkipedia on the topic?

Yes, $\sum_{i=1}^m i$ and $\sum_{n=1}^m n$ represent the same summation. In both cases, the expressions indicate the sum of integers from $1$ to $m$. The choice of index letter, $i$ or $n$, is arbitrary and does not affect the result of the summation.
The sum itself can be calculated by the formula:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^m i = \sum_{n=1}^m n = \frac{m(m+1)}{2}.
$$
So, both expressions yield the same value.

@Yves Daoust The two notations in the image represent different ways of summing terms.

First notation: $i + \sum_{i=1}^5 i$

This expression means adding the variable $i$ to the sum of $i$ from 1 to 5.
Explicitly, it is calculated as $i + (1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5)$.





Second notation: $\sum_{i=1}^5 \sum_{i=1}^7 i$

This expression is a double summation.
The inner sum $\sum_{i=1}^7 i$ calculates the sum of $i$ from 1 to 7.
Then, the outer sum $\sum_{i=1}^5$ indicates that this inner sum is repeated 5 times.
So it would be equivalent to adding the result of $\sum_{i=1}^7 i$ five times.



Note: In this second expression, there is a repeated index $i$ in both summations, which is unusual and could lead to ambiguity.
